# Three.js PlaneBufferGeometry not rendering

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I'm not able to render a planeBufferGeometry. Not sure what Im doing wrong. This is my first attempt with BufferGeometry. This works fine if I replace the code with a Geometry.Sphere or any other Geometry object.

```html
   
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 5, 20, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xCC0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

scene.add(plane);
    
    function update () {
      // Draw!
      renderer.render(scene, camera);

      // Schedule the next frame.
      requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }

    // Schedule the first frame.
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

CAmera Position

> const WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
>       const HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

```
// Set some camera attributes.
const VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
const ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
const NEAR = 0.1;
const FAR = 10000;

// Get the DOM element to attach to
const container =
    document.querySelector('#container');

// Create a WebGL renderer, camera
// and a scene
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const camera =
    new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        VIEW_ANGLE,
        ASPECT,
        NEAR,
        FAR
    );

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you see your object when you use `THREE.PlaneGeometry()`?

Comment: No, I dont see with Three.PlaneGeometry() too.

Comment: What position of your camera then?

Comment: const camera =
        new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            VIEW_ANGLE,
            ASPECT,
            NEAR,
            FAR
        );

Comment: I'm saying about `camera.position`

Comment: I'm not setting the position anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example with your code of instancing the buffer plane:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10); // set the position of the camera
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(5, 20, 32, 32);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xCC0000,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(plane);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```